# SVG animation works in Chrome & Safari, but not in Firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, cross-browser, svg-animate

I have a Logo as SVG paths, which I animated to be triggered by scrolling.
On Chrome & Safari it works like a charm (desktop & mobile), but not in Firefox.

This is the SVG (some letters removed to make it a bit anonymous):

```
<svg id="animated_logo-0" 
    encoding="UTF-8" 
    standalone="no" 
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    width="163" 
    viewBox="0 0 163 28">
    <g id="layer1">
        <g id="types">
            <g id="g-first">
                <animateTransform id="animate-contract-g-first-translate-0" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0" to="55" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                <animateTransform id="animate-expand-g-first-translate-0" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="55" to="0" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                <path id="type-E1" d="m 0,5 v 22.4 h 14.016 v -2.4 h -11.456 v -7.776 h 10.528 v -2.368 h -10.528 v -7.456 h 11.296 v -2.4 z"></path>
            </g>
            <g id="g-7" fill-opacity="1">
                <animate id="animate-contract-g-7-opacity-0" attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" from="1" to="0" fill="freeze"></animate>
                <animate id="animate-expand-g-7-opacity-0" attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" from="0" to="1" fill="freeze"></animate>
                <path id="type-M" d="m 32.70397,27.432 v -22.464 h 2.624 l 8.288,18.784 8.064,-18.784 h 2.592 v 22.464 h -2.496 v -16.672 l -7.264,16.896 h -1.824 l -7.456,-16.896 v 16.672 z"></path>
                <path id="type-E2" d="m 59.71192,5 v 22.4 h 14.016 v -2.4 h -11.456 v -7.776 h 10.528 v -2.368 h -10.528 v -7.456 h 11.296 v -2.4 z"></path>
                <path id="type-N" d="m 118.17578,27.4 v -22.4 h 2.912 l 11.968,18.464 v -18.464 h 2.592 v 22.4 h -2.848 l -12.032,-18.272 v 18.272 z"></path>
            </g>
            <g id="g-last" transform="translate(0)">
                <animateTransform id="animate-contract-g-last-translate-0" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0" to="-55" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                <animateTransform id="animate-expand-g-last-translate-0" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="-55" to="0" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                <path id="type-O" d="m 150.94376,4.392 c -6.592,0 -10.976,4.672 -10.976,11.648 0,7.136 4.352,11.936 10.976,11.936 6.656,0 11.04,-4.8 11.04,-11.936 0,-6.976 -4.416,-11.648 -11.04,-11.648 z m -8.192,11.648 c 0,-5.536 3.264,-9.152 8.192,-9.152 4.96,0 8.256,3.616 8.256,9.152 0,5.696 -3.296,9.44 -8.256,9.44 -4.928,0 -8.192,-3.744 -8.192,-9.44 z"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="g-dash" fill-opacity="0">
            <animate id="animate-contract-g-dash-opacity-0" attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" from="0" to="1" fill="freeze"></animate>
            <animate id="animate-expand-g-dash-opacity-0" attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" from="1" to="0" fill="freeze"></animate>
            <animateTransform id="animate-contract-g-dash-translate-0" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0" to="55" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
            <animateTransform id="animate-expand-g-dash-translate-0" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="55" to="0" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
            <rect id="Dash" x="22" y="0" width="11.456" height="2.4"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This is the function called to trigger the animation on scroll events:

```
function triggerAnimationTag(svg, animationId) {
  console.log(`trigger animation ${animationId} for svg id: ${svg.id}`);
  let animation = svg.getElementById(animationId);
  animation.beginElement();        
}
```

I checked in the FF console log: it's called and doesn't throw any errors. e.g.:

```
trigger animation animate-contract-g-first-translate-0 for svg id: animated_logo-0
```

I read somewhere FF follows the SVG standard closer than the other browsers, but don't know how to validate the SVG other than [this checker](https://svgcheck.toolforge.org/index.php). It says, everything is fine.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Seems OK to me on Firefox. Are you sure this example demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You can help us answering your question, by converting your code to a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I also don't see any problems withe the code provided. Like suggested, maybe you could write a simple example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sadly no news. Haven't found time to go back to this part of the project... But I will update, when I finally polish the part of the project.